# Power Bi Embedded Deployment

Tags: azure, powerbi

When trying to deploy Power Bi Embedded to Azure, I receive this error:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "Cannot create workspace collection 'demo' because it already exists.",
    "target": "demo"
  }
}

Though I do not actually have any workspace collections yet

Comment: It maybe trying to create a folder named 'demo' in your Documents. Check if there is already a folder named 'demo' in one of the public location. Also see if you can replicate the error on different machine.

Answer (score 4):

Workspace collection names are globally unique across all of Azure. You need to pick a unique name.